# select columns with patterns in data.table

Tags: r, select, data.table, multiple-columns

I have a data table with many columns like `real_0_h`, `real_1_h`, `real_2_h` and so on. Unfortunately, I have other columns named for instance real_dose.

my code looks like that (data.table package):

```
melt(dt, id.vars = c("id", "dose"), measure.vars = patterns("^real_"))
```

Like that, obviously `real_dose` will be selected as well, but I want to refer to `real_0_h:real_24_h` only (dplyr syntax). How is it done?

Comment: Please see this [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patterns` accepts a standard regular expression.
You could use following pattern to select only numbers after `real_`

```
melt(dt, id.vars = c("id", "dose"), measure.vars = patterns("^real_[0-9]"))
```

In the absence of reproducible example, this pattern can be tested with `grepl`:

```
grepl('^real_[0-9]',c('real_dose','real_0_h','real_24_h'))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```